# Parameter value in Data Factory Triggered pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cosmos-db, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline configured in azure data factory which basically does create a backup file (JSON) from a cosmosDB dataset and it's saved in  a blob storage, my problem comes when I want to schedule the copy task in a trigger, I see that I have to specify the value for windowStart (parameter already defined to name the JSON file with the date of the execution. ) as shown below:

Destination path:

[image]

And as you can see when I want to trigger it does ask me to specify the value for windowStart.

[image]

I tried below functions to specify that with no success so far:

```
"@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart}"
"@{formatDateTime(pipeline().startTime,'o')"
"@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
"@{formatDateTime(trigger().startTime,'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
```

And the error I always get is as shown below:

[image]

Have anyone any idea or way to fix that, or have someone faced the same issue before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this by creating the trigger using a JSON code as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "yourTriggerName",
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "YourPipelineName",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "windowStart": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2018-07-11T17:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        20
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        19
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And making emphasis of course, in line below:

```
"parameters": {
                        "windowStart": "@trigger().scheduledTime"
```

After that, the copy activity started to work as expected.

Comment: My understanding is that a scheduled trigger should automatically set the `windowStart` parameter. You should only need to specify a value if you manually trigger the pipeline. In this case, you can just enter the current date in [ISO-8601 format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)